# What is List&lt;Account&gt;?

Tags: apex

I was confused while reading this blog post: http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/10/02/preventing-recursive-future-method-calls-in-salesforce/

What do &lt AND &gt mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are called [`HTML Entities`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp).

- `&lt;` is the entity name for `<` (less than)
- `&gt;` is the entity name for `>` (greater than)

Seeing these entities just means there's something wrong with the rendering/content on that particular blog/post. In the case of your title, `List&lt;Account&gt;` is actually `List<Account>`.